# Loops not executing in functions C++

Tags: c++

Here's my code. Whenever I run the program, I expect that the **cout** statement in the  **for loop** in the function  **Binary()**  to execute. But whenever I input something, it gives me **0**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
long int Binary(int x){
    int temp=0,res=0;
    for(int i=x;i<0;i--){
        temp++;
        res=res+ pow(10,temp)*(i%2);
        i=i/2;
        cout<<i<<"  "<<res<<endl;
    }
    return res;
} 
int main(){
    int x; cin>>x;
    cout<<endl<<Binary(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at `for(int i=x;i<0;i--)` very carefully.  Is `i < 0` going to be true when you first enter the function?

Comment: Try input `-42`, and you will get output other than 0.

Comment: You shouldn't use `pow`, as it is a floating point function that may give inaccurate results.  Just use a (static) array of powers of 10.  Also, why would you want to constantly repeat calculating `pow`, for example, `pow(10,2)`, when you know it is 100 and can't be anything else?  That's why a table should be used, and second  entry in the table would be 100 (the entry number is the exponent value).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice#1452738

Comment: Rather than using a table of powers of 10, you could have a variable that gets multiplied by 10 in each iteration.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is a nice suggestion, but it's hardly essential. All integers can be represented by `double` up to `2**53`, which likely to be as large as OP wants and, depending on the platform, may even be larger than `int` can hold anyway. For all possible values that would give a result in range, the difference in computation time will be trillions of times smaller than the time for you to type your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the condition in your for loop is the opposite way round than your expect it. You seem to want it to continue looping until `i<0`. But it will actually loop **while** `i<0`. The condition is already not true when you enter the loop, so it will finish immediately without doing any iterations.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change the loop `i` check.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
long int Binary(int x){
    int temp=0,res=0;
    for(int i=x;i>0;i--){
        temp++;
        res=res+ pow(10,temp)*(i%2);
        i=i/2;
        cout<<i<<"  "<<res<<endl;
    }
    return res;
} 
int main(){
    int x; cin>>x;
    cout<<endl<<Binary(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Check the live version here http://cpp.sh/95z74

Comment: Nevertheless the program has no syntactic error and seems to be working fine without getting weird, but has logical errors in binary conversion and produces incorrect output.

Comment: @LegendrarySaiyan If you are happy with an answer then please show that by accepting the answer you found most helpful. That is likely to help stop discussion.